# How can I set NetBeans to use my own ant installation?

Tags: unix, netbeans, ant, path, classnotfoundexception

I did that successfully for Maven through NetBeans preferences setting Maven home to `/opt/local/share/java/maven3` but doing the same with Ant (`/opt/local/share/java/apache-ant`) but there NetBeans reports:

```
ERROR - Ant is misconfigured and cannot be run.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl

$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010

$ /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/ant/bin/ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick fix: copy-paste ~/.netbeans/7.0rc2/config/Preferences/org/apache into the corresponding 7.0 config folder.